# How to set state and use it in a function using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to set state and use it in  a callee function  using react and typescript.

What i am trying to do?

I have a function View and custom usehook named useLoad. within View function i call the useLoad and use it like in my code below,

```
export function useLoad() {
    const { refetch: refetchItems } = useGetItems();
    const { refetch: refetchOwnedItems } = useListOwnedItems();
    return async function() {
        await refreshCompany();
        refetchItems();
        refetchOwnedItems();
    };
}


function View() {
    const load = useLoad(); 
    //someother unrelated logic here
}
```

Now as you see within View i am using useLoad(). now i want to set a loading indicator during refreshCompany. so i set a loading state to true before refreshCompany() and set loading to false after that like below,

```
export function useLoad() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
    const { refetch: refetchItems } = useGetItems();
    const { refetch: refetchOwnedItems } = useListOwnedItems();
    return async function() {
        setLoading(true);
        await refreshCompany();
        setLoading(false);
        refetchItems();
        refetchOwnedItems();
    };
}
```

Now my point is how do i use this loading state within the View function. could someone help me with this. Or is there  a better way to set the loading state during refreshCompany.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return array from hook. More about [as const](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/hooks).

```
export function useLoad() {
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
    const { refetch: refetchItems } = useGetItems();
    const { refetch: refetchOwnedItems } = useListOwnedItems();
    const fetch = async function() {
        setLoading(true);
        await refreshCompany();
        setLoading(false);
        refetchItems();
        refetchOwnedItems();
    };

    return [loading, fetch] as const;
}

function View() {
    const [loading, fetch] = useLoad(); 
    //someother unrelated logic here
}
```

Comment: thanks but this is giving me  typeerror fetch is not a function.

Comment: @someuser2491 can you reproduce this typerror on codesandox?

Comment: ahh sorry that was my mistake within code. it works now